# What video capture boards are "plug-and-play" compatible?

Tags: video, hardware

I'm looking for a video capture board that works in Ubuntu without a lot of painful configuration or hassles.

I'm looking for an external USB-2.0 based capture board and I would prefer one with an onboard MPEG-encoder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hauppauge HD-PVR solves your problem if you're dealing with analog video. It works as V4L2 device with USB interface.

Inputs:

- Video

  - composite
  - s-video
  - component video (480i/p, 720p, 1080i)
- Audio

  - Analog stereo
  - s/pdif

Output:

- H.264
- MPEG-2

More info:

http://www.hauppauge.com/site/products/data_hdpvr.html

http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Index.php/Hauppauge_HD-PVR

Answer (score 1):

The list of supported chipsets is at http://www.exploits.org/v4l/  Anything that uses one of those video chips will work.